# Как проверить, что строка - число?

Tags: c++, xcode

В программе вводится переменная float (конечно же должны вводиться числовые значения), но интерфейс программы так построен, что пользователь часто вводит слово. Когда нажимается ввод вылазит куча сообщений об ошибке.

Как осуществить проверку того, что ввелось именно число, а не слово?

Comment: Вообще там float, я ошибся, в общем неважно.

Comment: Посмотрите [man strtof](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtof)

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать string ОМ(char ОМ), как предложил товарищ удаленный. можно так int a;
    if(scanf("%d",&a)!=1) если tru неверно.
scanf выводит сообщение об ошибке если a не число

Comment: или так if (Symbol >= '0' && Symbol <= '9')

Comment: В примере со `scanf` наверное вы имели в виду 1) `sscanf` 2) `%f` ?